# Cannot sort search results within nested objects in Elasticsearch 7

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to sort objects in ascending order but the sort doesn't work.

Here is a sort query below.

```
"sort":[
{
    "category.position": {
        "order":"asc",
        "mode":"min",
        "nested": {
            "path": "category",
            "filter": {
                "term": {"category_category_id":42} }
        }
    }
}]
```

And here are the objects below.

```
"name": "Yeti",
"category": [
        {
        "category_id": 42,
        "name": "Raamiga",
        "position": 3
        },
    ],
"name": "Venus",
"category": [
        {
        "category_id": 42,
        "name": "Raamiga",
        "position": 4
        }
    ],
```

Please, help! Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Solved. There was a typo… Must be "category.category_id" indtead of "category_category_id".